# T-SQL MIN of Subquery

Tags: t-sql

I have a query that tries to return a customer number and the number of *consecutive* years they've been a customer.  It does this by building a list of activity-year and customer, then comparing that to a list of possible years and returning the lowest year with no activity.  The problem is that the possible years list is a large cross-join.  I think this would run much more quickly if I could bake the EXCEPT logic inside the MIN and just reuse my list of 10 possible years.

The Query:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(D,3,9) AS Cust, MIN(SUBSTRING(D,1,1)) AS Years FROM 
(SELECT DISTINCT
  CAST (y.years AS VARCHAR) + '-' + CAST(pm.BillToCustomerId AS VARCHAR ) AS D
   FROM [DW_Mart].[dbo].[vProMaster] pm
   cross join 
   (VALUES ('0'),('1'),('2'),('3'),('4'),('5'),('6'),('7'),('8'),('9')) AS y(years)
        EXCEPT
    SELECT DISTINCT CAST (DATEDIFF(YEAR,[ShipmentDate],CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) AS VARCHAR)
 + '-' + CAST ([BillToCustomerId] AS VARCHAR ) AS D
   FROM [DW_Mart].[dbo].[vProMaster] pm ) AS X GROUP BY SUBSTRING(D,3,9)
```

My pseudocode revised query:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(D,3,9) AS Cust, MIN((VALUES ('0'),('1'),('2'),('3'),('4'),('5'),('6'),('7'),('8'),('9')) EXCEPT SUBSTRING(D,1,1)) AS Years FROM 
(SELECT DISTINCT CAST (DATEDIFF(YEAR,[ShipmentDate],CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) AS VARCHAR)
 + '-' + CAST ([BillToCustomerId] AS VARCHAR ) AS D
   FROM [DW_Mart].[dbo].[vProMaster] pm ) AS X GROUP BY SUBSTRING(D,3,9)
```

Answer (score 0):

how about something like ...

```
select billtocustomerid, max( DATEDIFF(YEAR,[ShipmentDate],CURRENT_TIMESTAMP))
from dw_mart.dbo.vpromaster
group by billtocustomerid
```

Comment: Good catch, but I should have been clearer.  We're looking for the number of consecutive years with activity.  If they had activity in year 0, 1, 2, and 4, the answer would be 3.  That's why the EXCEPT against the list of possible years works well (but very slowly).

Comment: oh, consecutive, that's a key word :)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that the cross join crushed the server.
I’m not sure how proud I am of this puppy, but it works and it’s quick:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(D,10,9) AS Cust,
CHARINDEX('1',RIGHT('00000000'+(CAST (11111111-SUM(CAST(SUBSTRING(D,1,8) AS INT)) AS VARCHAR)),8)) AS Years
  FROM 
(SELECT DISTINCT RIGHT('00000000'+(CAST (POWER(10,(FLOOR(8-DATEDIFF(MONTH,[ShipmentDate],CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)/12))) AS VARCHAR)),8)
+ '-' + CAST ([BillToCustomerId] AS VARCHAR ) AS D
FROM [DW_Mart].[dbo].[vProMaster] pm
where ShipmentDate < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP and ShipmentDate > DATEADD(YEAR,-8,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)) AS X GROUP BY SUBSTRING(D,10,9)
```